# Filter action by $routeParams

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to structure my routes similar to the way Rails does. I have some routes setup similar to this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/posts', {
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/views/posts.html'
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/new', {
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/views/posts.html',
  doNew: true
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/:postID', {
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/views/posts.html'
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/:postID/edit', {
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/views/posts.html',
  doEdit: true
});
```

`PostCtrl` has the following at the bottom:

```
if ($routeParams.doNew) {
  console.log('action: new');
} else if ($routeParams.doEdit) {
  console.log('action: edit', $routeParams.postID);
} else if ($routeParams.libraryID) {
  console.log('action: show', $routeParams.postID);
} else {
  console.log('action: index');
}
```

`action: show` is printed when the path is `/posts/new` or `/posts/2` or `/posts/2/edit`. What can I filter to have the controller route to the appropriate action?

Comment: 99% you should create separate controllers for each route.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. The reason to have different controllers is if the data they setup on the scope is fundamentally different. For things like new, edit, show it will be virtually identical so it makes sense to reuse the same controller. The 'list' view might be different and warrant it's own controller/template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out an easier way to implement Rails-inspired actions.

Define routes:

```
$routeProvider.when('/posts', {
  templateUrl: '/views/posts/index.html',
  controller: 'PostsCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/new', {
  templateUrl: '/views/posts/index.html',
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  action: 'new'
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/:postID', {
  templateUrl: '/views/posts/index.html',
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  action: 'show'
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/:postID/edit', {
  templateUrl: '/views/posts/index.html',
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  action: 'edit'
});
```

Then add an event handler for `$routeChangeSuccess`:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function ($rootScope, $route) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (currentRoute, previousRoute) {
    if ($route.current.action) {
      $rootScope.action = $route.current.action;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Then in your controller, you can branch on `$scope.action`:

```
if ($scope.action === 'new') {
  $scope.newPost();
} else if ($scope.action === 'show') {
  Post.get($routeParams.postID).then($scope.showPost);
} else if ($scope.action === 'edit') {
  Post.get($routeParams.postID).then($scope.editPosts);
}
```

Normally I probably would have separate controllers for these routes, but on the app I'm building; `new`, `show`, `edit` are displayed in a modal over the index of all the "Posts".

Answer (score 2):

You can make it easy by just adding a resolve:

```
$routeProvider.when('/posts', {
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/views/posts.html'
  resolve: {
       action: function(){return 'list';}
  }
});
$routeProvider.when('/posts/new', {
  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/views/posts.html'
  resolve: {
       action: function(){return 'new';}
  }
});
```

etc..

you can then just inject `action` into your controller:

```
controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, action){
    if(action==='new'){
       console.log('new');
     }
});
```

Comment: Adding `resolve` works, but seems really wordy for what gets accomplished. I'll just watch `$routeChangeSuccess` and set `$rootScope.action` if the current route defines an action.